# Как создать xml на python используя xml.etree.ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

создаю xml следующим кодом :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 ... some code to create xml ...
mydata = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")
myfile = open("test_1.xml" , "wb")
myfile.write(mydata)
```

и получаю xml в строке. я так понимаю, это из-за функции `tostring` но не могу найти/реализовать что бы это было как на примере ниже

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Comment: Я так понял в этом инструменте нет форматирования, [вот похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402323/use-xml-etree-elementtree-to-print-nicely-formatted-xml-files) с проблемой, где для форматирования рекомендуют использовать minidom

Comment: Я так понял, что в представленном ваме тикете, указано парсинг xml а мне нужно создать его с нуля.

Comment: Вы хотите в коде создать XML, чтобы она была как в вашем примере с `<data>`?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример, какие данные сейчас записываются в файл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для создания `XML` используйте объекты `ET.Element`:

- Конструктор `ET.Element` позволит задать название тега, а его именованные параметры в атрибуты.
- Содержимое задается через `.text`
- А добавление вложенных тегов через метод `.append`

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/dd7f0f3b60f6f240d41aed3116813170dee32151/XML/xml.etree.ElementTree__examples/create_xml.py):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('data')

country = ET.Element('country', name="Liechtenstein")

rank = ET.Element('rank', updated="yes")
rank.text = '2'
country.append(rank)

year = ET.Element('year')
year.text = '2008'
country.append(year)

gdppc = ET.Element('gdppc')
gdppc.text = '141100'
country.append(gdppc)

country.append(ET.Element('neighbor', name="Austria", direction="E"))
country.append(ET.Element('neighbor', name="Switzerland", direction="W"))

root.append(country)

country = ET.Element('country', name="Singapore")
root.append(country)

# NOTE: По аналогии выше сами заполните нужные вам страны

xml_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")
print(xml_str.decode(encoding="utf-8"))
# <data>
#   <country name="Liechtenstein">
#     <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
#     <year>2008</year>
#     <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
#     <neighbor direction="E" name="Austria" />
#     <neighbor direction="W" name="Switzerland" />
#   </country>
#   <country name="Singapore" />
# </data>
```

Встроенной в `xml.etree.ElementTree` возможности получить `XML` с отступами (pretty-print) не нашел, но [это возможно](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d3e1875eb558bf2d868e9b745b3430b9834a8cac/XML/xml.etree.ElementTree__examples/pretty_print.py#L13):

```
def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i
```

Перед сохранением `XML` в строку или в файл вызовите `indent(root)`:

```
...

indent(root)

xml_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", method="xml")
```

А чтобы получить `xml-declaration`, строку вида `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`, нужно через `ET.ElementTree` сохранить `XML`:

```
etree = ET.ElementTree(root)
f = io.BytesIO()
etree.write(f, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
print(f.getvalue().decode(encoding="utf-8"))
# <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
# <data>
#   <country name="Liechtenstein">
#     <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
...

# Чтобы сразу в файл записать:
myfile = open("test_1.xml" , "wb")
etree.write(myfile, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```